# How to render html inside Template literals?

Tags: javascript, html

I explain my scenario, the users enter content through a WYSIWYG editor that is persisted in the database, in another place of the application this content and another one is obtained through an ajax request, here I use template literals to build a html structure with the data that is finally inserted into the view using `innerHTML` in a destination DOM element.

I require that the content that was added through the WYSIWYG editor be displayed as html, with lodash function `_.unescape ()` I get the free content of html special characters, but this is not shown as html but as a html string

I share the general idea of ​​the implementation:

Template literal

```
`...
<div>${getHTML(dataset.message)}</div>
...`
```

Javascript

```
function getHTML(message) {
    const html = _.unescape(message).replace('\\', '');
    const parser = new DOMParser();
    const dom = parser.parseFromString(html, 'text/html')

    return dom;
}
```

Output

```
[object HTMLDocument]
```

If instead of the `dom` variable I return the `html` variable in the view I get for example `<p>some content <strong>goes here</strong></ p>` and I require this content to be displayed as regular view html

Any idea please about showing the content as html?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason this happens is because [DOMParser returns a HTMLDocument object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) and when you try to set HTMLDocument object as innerHTML of any element it calls `toString()` of this object - which is `[object HTMLDocument]`.

You can try this yourself:

```js
const html = '<div>Some html content</div>';

const parser = new DOMParser();
const doc = parser.parseFromString(html, "text/html");

console.log(doc.toString()); // [object HTMLDocument]
```

Good news is, that in your case you don't need the `DOMParser` at all. All you need to unescape the given string and set it as innerHTML of your element:

```js
// Your modified getHTML function
const getHTML = message => _.unescape(message).replace('\\', '');

// Container in which your want to render the HTML
const container = document.getElementById('container');

// Dummy HTML representing your data from the database
const html = _.escape('<h1>Your content</h1>');

// Dummy template representing your template literal
const template = `
<div>
  ${getHTML(html)}
</div>
`;

// Set the resolved dummy template as content of the dummy container
container.innerHTML = template;
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, sadly I am not able to use `innerHTML` because in this case the code that call the function is inside a Template literal `<div>${getHTML(dataset.message)}</div>`

Comment: In that case you just call the updated `getHTML` function inside the template literal.

Comment: Is this using underscore?

Comment: lodash only using `unescape` function

Comment: Op hasn't mentioned iodash, you shouldn't use libraries that aren't tagged. Or at the very least explain this.

Comment: @Liam 'with lodash function _.unescape ()' :)

Comment: hello again user3210641, thanks for the time you have invested in this question, but sadly I do not get the same result in local, I changed the logic to adapt to your example but I still get the html text string instead of the rendered html

Answer (score -2):

Yeap this will work `return dom.firstChild.innerHTML;`

Comment: Edit your answer, don't just write another one