# Variables As Arguments To Tag Functions

Tags: javascript, template-literals

Is it possible to create a tag function when the template literal is a variable?
e.g. instead of this

```
render`<h1>Hello World</h1>`
```

Is there any way to do this?

```
const template = `<h1>Hello World</h1>`
render(template)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to render html inside Template literals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50763016/how-to-render-html-inside-template-literals)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not possible. [Tagged templates](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#tagged_templates) are a special syntax where `render` will get called with a string array and all the `${value}` values. By storing it in a variable like that, the template literal is instead interpreted as a regular template literal to be converted to a string instead of a function call.

Of course, if all your `render` function does is concatenation of the template and its variables, it doesn't matter. But mind that the variables inside the template literal are already evaluated when you store it in a variable, it can't get re-evaluated later.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I suspected as much.